# grid layout with padding/margin between items

Tags: html, css, grid

How to add spaces (padding), between items on a grid layout? I tried add the padding to div but the spaces are not equal.

```css
div{
   width:calc(100% / 3);
  padding:10px;
box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
    
}

img{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid;
    display:block;
}

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
<div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
```

Comment: r u looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/wsekefun/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
 

  div{
   padding:5px;
   box-sizing:border-box;
   overflow:hidden;
  }

  div > div{
      width:calc(100% / 3);
      float:left;   
    }

img{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid;
    display:block;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but the spaces are not equal, it's ugly.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you want it?

Comment: if you notice the 2nd and 3rd spaces are larger than the 1st and 4th spaces.

Comment: For that you need to add a wrapper div. I've updated my snippet. Please check.